# is_permutation method from #include<algorithm> showing wrong Output

Tags: c++, algorithm

The output of the following snippet showing "Same elements", but They are not the same.

Here is my code:

```
list<int> list_var{1,2,3,2,4,0};
vector<int> vector_var{2,4,1,2,3};
if(is_permutation(list_var.begin(), list_var.end(), vector_var.begin()))
     cout<<"Same elements\n"; 
else
    cout<<"Not same elements\n";
```

Comment: Undefined if sequence2 is shorter than sequence1.  https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/is_permutation/

Answer (score 0):

Please share your output because in my case it is giving correct Output "Not same"
I am using Visual Studio code and Clang Compiler.
Code:-

```
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
list<int> list_var{1,2,3,2,4,0};
vector<int> vector_var{2,4,1,2,3};
if(is_permutation(list_var.begin(), list_var.end(), vector_var.begin()))
     cout<<"Same elements\n"; 
else
    cout<<"Not same elements\n";

}
```

Comment: It's UB, so inconsistent behavior shouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

From the reference for [`std::is_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation):

> Returns true if there exists a permutation of the elements in the range [first1, last1) that makes that range equal to the range [first2,last2), where last2 denotes first2 + (last1 - first1) if it was not given.

Since you have not specified the end of the second range it needs to be as large as the first one (containing 6 elements in this case). All these elements must be dereferencable, but since your second range doesn't have enough elements, you are invoking undefined behavior.